# Does the standard guarantee, that std::string::resize will not do anything, if the new size is the same as the old one?

Tags: c++, string, resize

As the title says:

> Does the standard guarantee, that std::string::resize will not do anything, if the new size is the same as the old one?

<sub>Of course, I can test it, but it could be UB, so testing will not work here.</sub>
<sub>In cppreference.com and cplusplus.com, the doc says nothing about this case</sub>

Example:

```
std::string s( "asd" );
// s.size() is 3
s.resize( 3 );    // will this affect **somehow** the string?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there are no guarantees. An implementation *could* reallocate the string to a new buffer, to reduce its `capacity()`.

The standard says:

> *Effects*: Alters the length of the string designated by `*this` as follows:
>
> — If `n <= size()`, the function replaces the string designated by `*this` with a string of length n whose elements are a copy of the initial elements of the original string designated by `*this`.
>
> — If `n > size()`, the function replaces the string designated by `*this` with a string of length n whose first `size()` elements are a copy of the original string designated by `*this`, and whose remaining elements are all initialized to c.

Comment: In fact, that seems to *require* that the implementation conceptually move the string to a new buffer. The new buffer is permitted to have the same address as the old buffer, so by the as-if rule, the implementation can optimise this to a no-op, but that's not required.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder is `charT` of `basic_string` allowed to be a user-defined type with a copy constructor, and if so whether this text can be construed as a requirement that `resize` calls it `size()` times. Copy elision does not apply here if so.

Comment: Anyway, `[string.require]` is also relevant: "References, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements of a basic_string sequence may be invalidated by the following uses of that basic_string object: ... Calling non-const member functions, except operator[], at, front, back, begin, rbegin, end, and rend". So that re-iterates that `resize()` can relocate the elements, with no special requirement when the new size is less than the old.

Comment: No, charT has to be a POD type. (first sentence of clause 21).

Answer (score 1):

ISO/IEC 14882:2011(E) § 21.4.4:

`void resize(size_type n, charT c);`

*Requires:* n <= max_size()

*Throws:* length_error if n > max_size().

*Effects:* Alters the length of the string designated by *this as follows:

- If n <= size(), the function replaces the string designated by *this with a string of length n
  whose elements are a copy of the initial elements of the original string designated by *this.
- If n > size(), the function replaces the string designated by *this with a string of length n
  whose first size() elements are a copy of the original string designated by *this, and whose
  remaining elements are all initialized to c.